# disable header file suggestions in CLion

Tags: clion

I am looking at C source code intended for Linux builds on a Windows PC with JetBrains CLion IDE. CLion keeps suggesting I include a header file for some undefined symbols, but I do not want to see these pop-up suggestions. The pop-ups make it difficult to read the code.

How can I disable header file suggestions in CLion?

Answer (score 1):

There are two aspects:

- Disabling include file suggestions. Starting from CLion 1.0: Settings | Editor | General | Auto Import | uncheck the "Show import popup".
- When the suggestion pops up, it should at least be correct :-) There are many bugs opened on this behavior, check for example https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-704. Almost completely fixed starting from CLion 1.0.

**EDIT** Fixed starting from CLion 1.0 (Apr 2015).